# Update rows in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (Fruits) with following column

```
Fruit_Name(varchar2(10)) | IsDuplicate Number(1)
            Mango                    0
           Orange                    0
           Mango                     0
```

What i have to do is to update IsDuplicate column  to 1 where Fruit_Name in Distinct i.e

```
 Fruit_Name(varchar2(10)) | IsDuplicate Number(1)
            Mango                    1
           Orange                    1
           Mango                     0
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Technically not a problem, but... Why should IsDuplicate be 0 for the actual duplicate and 1 otherwise? That is, the column should probably named differently, maybe 'IsFirstOccurrence' or something along the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it as far as I can tell

```
update fruits 
  set is_duplicate = 
      (
        select case 
                  when dupe_count > 1 and row_num = 1 then 1
                  else 0
                end as is_dupe
        from (
           select f2.fruit_name,
                  count(*) over (partition by f2.fruit_name) as dupe_count,
                  row_number() over (partition by f2.fruit_name order by f2.fruit_name) as row_num,
                  rowid as row_id
           from fruits f2
        ) ft 
        where ft.row_id = fruits.rowid
          and ft.fruit_name = fruits.fruit_name
      )
```

**Edit**
But instead of actually updating the table, why don't you create a view that returns the information. Depending on the size of the table it might be more efficient.

```
create view fruit_dupe_view
as 
select fruit_name,
       case 
          when dupe_count > 1 and row_num = 1 then 1
          else 0
        end as is_duplicate
from (
   select fruit_name,
          count(*) over (partition by fruit_name) as dupe_count,
          row_number() over (partition by fruit_name order by fruit_name) as row_num
   from fruits 
) ft
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you have a rowid in there, he doesn't have id in his table, where did your rowid come from?This query is a bit high level for me sorry if i am being stupid.

Comment: @EmreVeryaz: it's an internal column from Oracle uniquely identifying every row.

Comment: If that actually works, I stand corrected. Heck of a mess to go through to fix a bad table design though.

Comment: @Brian: I agree, the information can always be retrieved quite easily.

Comment: @Brian: yes that's possible. Especially inside a single statement. You just cannot rely on the fact that the rowid from a previous statement (or transaction) still refers to the same row.

Comment: @Brian I was thinking if you can use stored procedures, like one of them returns a Fruit_Name and the other COUNT s how many times it occured in the table and set 1 if COUNT is greater than 1 but I cant seem to write the code, maybe @a_horse can help with that.

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz: I still think a view is the better solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Straight and simple -- you can't.  Not with vanilla SQL.  SQL is a set-based processing language, and you do things in sets.  There is no way for SQL to know which one of your many Mango's should be tagged 1.  You can probably tag one of them with 1 using windowing functions or ROWNUM etc. in a SELECT, but I don't think it can be done with an UPDATE.

In other words, your table lacks a unique key in the first place, so it is not something that SQL is designed to process.

However, you may try adding a sequential primary key to each row.  Then you can easily write an UPDATE query to set to 1 all the rows with COUNT > 1 and key = MIN(key).

In other words, you really have to look at your database design.  Relational databases are not supposed to contain "duplicates".  That fact that you need to mark something as a duplicate means that your tables are designed wrong in the first place.  The database should not even *allow* duplications to enter into its data.

Comment: actually,this table is an external table of oracle.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is internal or external.  You can't distinguish duplicates in an UPDATE with SQL -- that's just not what SQL was designed for.  Nothing to do with the database -- you can throw in anything you want in there.  You just can't manipulate it with a language that is designed to be set-based.